# Guide me : XSD to XML converter

Tags: xml, html, xsd, jaxb

We have to use JAXB framework and html 5. Thing is , we need to browse one xsd file. Based on elements of xsd, we need to generate dynamic GUI to get data for each and every elements. And then, with that data, we will have to generate xml file.

How do I start with and how would I go?

I appreciate if any of you suggest a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to start from raw XSD documents. Find a processor that gives you access to a compiled schema at the component level. There's an API in Xerces for this, and Saxon offers SCM which is an XML representation of the schema components.

Even then, it's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

On the Java platform, I would consider [XForms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_Implementations) instead. As for writing my own, the API I would use on Java for XSD processing is [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/). As Michael was pointing out, for all but simple XSDs, it is not a trivial task.